# How many positive solutions are there for $x_1+x_2+x_3+...+x_{2r}=2k$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{r}x_{2i}=\sum_{i=1}^{r}x_{2i-1}$

Tags: combinatorics

I need to find how many positive solutions are there for the following :

$x_1+x_2+x_3+...+x_{2r}=2k$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{r}x_{2i}=\sum_{i=1}^{r}x_{2i-1}$

I don't if I approach this right this is what I did :

since $\sum_{i=1}^{r}x_{2i}=\sum_{i=1}^{r}x_{2i-1}$ therefore $x_1=x_2,x_3=x_4,...,x_{2r-1}=x_{2r}$ using this equality and the first equation we get that $\implies x_1+x_2+...+x_r=k$ so I get that $CC\binom{k}{r}$ but for some reason the result is $(CC\binom{k}{r})^2$.

Any ideas how to approach this?

Thank you!

Comment: You can't conclude that $x_1=x_2, x_3=x_4,\cdots$; you can only say that the evens have a sum of k and the odds have a sum of k.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\sum_{i=1}^{r}x_{2i}=\sum_{i=1}^{r}x_{2i-1}$ both these sums have to be equal to $k$, hence the number of solutions is given by the number of solutions of $x_1+x_3+\ldots+x_{2r-1}=k$ times the number of solutions of $x_2+x_4+\ldots+x_{2r}=k$, i.e. by:

$$ \left[[x^k]\left(x+x^2+x^3+\ldots\right)^r\right]^2 = \left[[x^k]\frac{x^r}{(1-x)^r}\right]^2 = \color{red}{\binom{k-1}{r-1}^2}.$$
Have a look at [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29).

Comment: Wouldn't it be $\binom{k-1}{r-1}^2$?

Comment: @user84413: yes, you're right, fixed.

Answer (score 3):

HINT: How many positive solutions are there for

$$\sum_{i=1}^rx_{2i}=k\;?\tag{1}$$

How many for

$$\sum_{i=1}^rx_{2i-1}=k\;?\tag{2}$$

Any positive solution to $(1)$ can be combined with any positive solution to $(2)$ to get a solution to your problem, and every solution to your problem arises in this way.